# How to unlock a user in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

How to unlock a user in azure ad using the graph api. I did not seen any solution in Microsoft docs. Is there any solution available to do this.

I really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is [not possible for administrators to unlock the users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout#how-smart-lockout-works)' cloud accounts if they have been locked out by the Smart Lockout capability. The administrator must wait for the lockout duration to expire. However, the user can unlock by using the self-service password reset (SSPR) from a trusted device or location.

You can however voice your interest in such a feature or support [similar ones](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36694495-azure-ad-smart-lockout-unlock-capability-for-admin) in the [Azure AD Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=166251).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way if you have an Azure virtual server. Go to features and install the AD DS and AD LDS tools then you can unlock a user as normal.

[image: AD DS and AD LDS tools Option]